# Wrote the code for sorting. Getting timeout error. Any ideas how to get it working (PS:started coding a week ago)

Tags: c, sorting, numeric

The following code is supposed to do sorting by assigning indexes based on greater or less than. eg for 5,17,13,21,6 5 is greater than 0 numbers, 17 is greater than 3 numbers 13 is greater than 2 number 21 is greater than 4 numbers and 6 is greater than 1 number. so we use these indexes and then place the numbers in new array accordingly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
        int main()
        {
            int i,j,w[4],z[4],x[4];
            x[0]=0;x[1]=0;x[2]=0;x[3]=0;


           w[0]=1; w[1]=3; w[2]=7; w[3]=15;

           for(i=0; i<4; i++)
           {
               for(j=0; j<4; i++)
                  {    
                      if (w[j] < w[i]) { x[i] = x[i] + 1;}
                  ;}
           ;}

           for(i=0; i<4; i++) {z[x[i]]=w[i];}

           for(i=0; i<4; i++) {printf("%d",z[i]);}

        }
```

Comment: In the `for j` loop you increment the i instead of the j

Comment: 'started coding a week ago', yes, it shows:(   The single-letter vars are almost meaningless and you seem to have done no debugging of your own :(   Don't try to write any more code, not a single line, until you have learned about your debugger and debugging in general.

Answer (score 1):

You're incrementing i in this for loop but checking for j< 4

```
for(j=0; j<4; i++)
  {    
  if (w[j] < w[i]) { x[i] = x[i] + 1;}
  ;}
```

Comment: Don't bother answering typo questions. Just comment and vote to close.

Comment: can you please elaborate how? are you saying about the x[i] part?

Comment: @SaketShrivastava: `for(j=0; j<4; i++)` -> `for(j=0; j<4; j++)`

Comment: Thanks @PaulR. was changing everything else but missed this. :)